# using 2 dimensional arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

Can someone help me write a C program that adds equivalent elements of two-dimensional arrays named Array1 and Array2? Both arrays should have two rows and three columns.

Array1

```
10  20  30  
40  50  60
```

Array2

```
24  36  48  
16  12  8
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it for *one*-dimensional arrays?

Comment: If you want, you can simplify them by using a 1d array and access it as `foo[ (y * line) + x]`

Comment: You're asking about a C program, but your question is tagged C++. Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

2-D arrays are represented continuously in memory in C/C++, so this should work:

```
void arraySum(int* sum, const int* a, const int* b, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int a[2][3] = ...;
int b[2][3] = ...;
int c[2][3];
arraySum((int*)c, (const int*)a, (const int*)b, 2, 3);
```

Or, more matrix-ey C++:

```
template<int R, int C>
void arraySum(int sum[R][C], const int a[R][C], const int b[R][C])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
    }
}

int a[2][3] = ...;
int b[2][3] = ...;
int c[2][3];
arraySum<2,3>(a, b, c);
```

(Apologies for the first answer in C.)